# Uint16Array not a valid argument for String.fromCharCode.apply

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs

I am having a strange problem concerning my unit tests of a conversion between an array buffer and a string.

This code is taken from: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String. Works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3DH9/

```
function ab2str(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}

alert(ab2str(str2ab('foo')));
```

I implemented the code and wrote a unit test in jasmine for it. Here i get a strange error, saying `TypeError: '[object Uint16Array]' is not a valid argument for 'Function.prototype.apply' (evaluating 'new Uint16Array(buf)')`

I am running PhantomJS 1.9.7  and Node v0.10.22

If i log it to the console it is `Object{prototype: Object{subarray: function subarray() { ... }, BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 2, set: function set() { ... }}, BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 2}`

My Chrome Browser instead implements this function in native code.

It seems that `String.fromCharCode` can not be applied to array like objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in PhantomJS:

See https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11172